# What's the chance level of the f-measure?

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, accuracy

I know that the accuracy level of chance for unbalanced two classes problem is the number of the data points belong to the class contains the majority of the data points over the number of all data points. What about the f-score? What's the level of chance of it?